# Show that if $X$ is a solution of $X'=A(t)X$ with $A$ a matrix and $X(0)$ with positive coefficients, $X(t)$ has positive positive coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Let $A : \mathbb R^+ \to M_n(\mathbb R^+) \in C(\mathbb R^+,M_n(\mathbb R^+) )$ and $X$ a solution of $X'=AX$ such that $X(0)$ with positive coefficients $(\ge 0)$.

I need to show that : $\forall t\in \mathbb R^+, X(t)$ has positive coefficients $(\ge 0)$.

I am stuck. I thought of using the exponential function for matrices. However, I can use it only for $A$ a constant (at my level).

I think we should begin with the case where $X(0)$ has strictly positive coefficients $(> 0)$. It may help for the general case.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Maybe we can use the fact that $X$ is continuous at $t=0$. I think if we say that $X(0)$ has strictly positive coefficients then we know that near $0$ X will have positive values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching, I think I have found a demonstration. Let me know if it seems right.
 In order to solve for the general case, we will first prove with the case where $X(0)$ has strictly positive coefficients.

### Strictly positive coefficients

The general idea here is to use the part $AX$. Since if from the start $X_0$ has strictly positive coefficients, it looks like all the coefficients of $X$ will grow. Thus, we will prove by contradiction.

Let $X(t) = (x_1(t),\dots,x_n(t))^T$ with $x_i(0)>0$ be a solution of $X' = AX$.
Suppose that $\exists i_0,\exists t_0>0$ such that $x_{i_0}(t_0) = 0$.

Let $\theta_{i_0} = \inf x_{i_0}^{-1}(\{0\})$ (It exists because $t_0\in x_{i_0}^{-1}(\{0\}) \subset \mathbb R^+$ ),
We can show that $\theta_{i_0} = \min x_{i_0}^{-1}(\{0\}) $ with the use of a sequence and the fact that $x_{i_0}\in C(\mathbb R^+,\mathbb R)$.
$\forall i\in[1,n],$ let $\theta_i = \min x_{i}^{-1}(\{0\})$ if it exists or $+\infty$ if not.
Finally, let $\theta_k = \min \theta_i \in\mathbb R^+_*$. $\theta_k$ corresponds to the smallest value where one of the coefficient of $X$ equal $0$.

Now, by the intermediate value theorem, we have : $\forall t\in[0,\theta_k], \forall i, x_i(t) \ge 0$.
However, we know that $X'=AX$ so:

$$\forall i\in[1,n], \forall t\in [0,\theta_k], x_i'(t)=\sum_{j=0}^n a_{i,j}(t)x_j(t)\ge 0$$
To conclude, we have $\forall t\in [0,\theta_k], x_k'(t) \ge 0$. So $x_k$ grows in $[0,\theta_k]$. We have $x_k(0)\le x_k(\theta_k)=0$.
We have a contradiction !
Then, by the intermediate value theorem, we have $\forall t\in \mathbb R^+,\forall i, x_i(t) > 0$. We finally prove for this case.

### General Case

Now, for the general case, we will approximate the problem. So instead of working with $X(0)$ positive coefficient, we will work with $X_{\varepsilon,0} = X(0)+(\varepsilon,\dots,\varepsilon)^T$ and will tend $\varepsilon \to 0^+$. We will choose $X_\varepsilon$ the solution of $X' =AX$ with $X_\varepsilon (0)=X_{\varepsilon,0}$.

Let $\mathcal S_E$ be the set of all solutions for : $X'=AX$.
We have this property : $$\phi_t :
\begin{array}{lrcl}
\mathcal S_E & \longrightarrow & \mathcal M_{n,1}(\mathbb R) \\
X & \longmapsto & X(t) 
\end{array} \text{ is an isomorphism
}$$

Now, let $X\in \mathcal S_E$ with $X(0)$ having positive coefficients, we have : $$\forall t>0, \forall \varepsilon >0, X_\varepsilon(t) = \phi_t(X_\varepsilon) = \phi_t(\phi_0^{-1}(X_{\varepsilon,0})) = (\phi_t \circ \phi_0^{-1})(X_{\varepsilon,0})$$

However, $\forall t>0, \phi_t \circ \phi_0^{-1} \in \mathcal L(\mathcal M_{n,1}(\mathbb R))$.
So, $\forall t>0, \phi_t \circ \phi_0^{-1} \in C(\mathcal M_{n,1}(\mathbb R))$ and $X_{0,\varepsilon}\to X(0)$ when $\varepsilon \to 0$. We get :

$$\forall t>0, X_\varepsilon(t) = (\phi_t \circ \phi_0^{-1})(X_{\varepsilon,0}) \to_{\varepsilon} (\phi_t \circ \phi_0^{-1})(X(0))=X(t)$$

And according to the first part $\forall \varepsilon >0, \forall t>0, X_\varepsilon(t)$ has positive coefficients.

By limit, $\forall t>0, X(t)$ has positive coefficients !

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set of positive $t$'s such that at least one coefficient of $X(t)$ is $<0.$ Assume by contradiction that this open set is non empty and let $(a,b)$ be one of its connected components. Then, all coefficients of $X(a)$ are $\ge0$ but at least one coefficient of $X'(a)$ is $<0,$ which is not consistent with the hypothesis on $A.$